# Get all tags of a repository with JGit

Tags: java, tags, jgit

I want to get a list of all tags of a repository together with the tagger and the commit-IDs with JGit.

First I tried the `Git.tagList().call()` command and parse the tags:

```
objectIdOfTag = oneResultOfTheTagList.getObjectId(); 
// or should I call getPeeledObjectId() here?

RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository);
RevTag tag = walk.parseTag(objectIdOfTag);
```

This works for my repository, but I am unsure if this is the correct way: Is it correct to call `Ref.getObjectId()` or should I call `Ref.getPeeledObjectId()`? (What is a "*peeled* ObjectId"?)

Is there a difference between lightweight and annotated tags when retrieving the tag list  with JGit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getObjectId` is correct here. In the case of an annotated tag, you want to get the ID of the annotated tag object, not the ID of the commit the tag finally points to. See also the [Javadoc of Ref](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Ref.html).

To parse the tag, you will have to handle both the lightweight and annotated cases:

```
RevObject object = walk.parseAny(objectIdOfTag);
if (object instanceof RevTag) {
    // annotated
} else if (object instanceof RevCommit) {
    // lightweight
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, it could be helpful to look at how EGit uses the JGit API in such cases, see [EGit contributor guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide) for setup instructions.

Comment: One last question: Can I get the name of a *lightweight* tag with the `ListTagCommand` (For `RevTag` I can use `revTag.getTagName()`.) ? (Or should I create my own `RevWalk` to get all tags?)

Comment: You can get the name via `Ref#getName()`, which will return e.g. `"refs/tags/my-tag"`. To get the "short name", use `Repository.shortenRefName()`.